# Writing equations in line with text

Tags: mathematics

I'm not sure if this belongs on math.stackexchange, but If I were to write:

We know a > b,    c > d,   e > f,     and f>g.

without the extra space,

We know a > b, c > d,   e > f,     and f > g

it becomes confusing as whether I mean a is greater than b and c which are both greater than d and e which are both greater than f.  However I'm told it's bad to have additional space.

Comment: I don’t think anyone would think that meant “a is greater than both b and c which are both greater than d and e...  Especially inline, the commas separate Items in a list.  The space (or lack of space) would not affect my understanding of the sentence- it just looks like inconsistent formatting.

Comment: Who told you it's bad to have extra space? If this is a journal-imposed space constraint, the journal should have guidelines on how to deal with equations.

Comment: To make it clearer you can parenthesise each condition: spaces between symbols and operators are generally considered to be non-functional, but aesthetically pleasing. We know (a > b), (c > d), (e > f), and (f > g).

Comment: You can use e > f > g without any ambiguity.

Comment: @jimm101 in that case I would have to write  a > b> d > f  and a > c > d > f . and a > b >  e > f . and a > c >  e > f  and that still doesn't solve what if I write a>b and c>d and e>f

Comment: Ah, missed your bottom part. It seems there you've written a > (b,c) > (d,e) > f > g. The parentheses should be grouping things that belong together. The way it's phrased above, grouping is open to interpretation.

Comment: well I didn't write (b,c)>(d,e)   but generally (b,c) > (d,e) means b>d and  c>e but thats it

Comment: Hmm. That's not the convention in my textbooks. In the case where (b,c) hasn't been defined as some tuple, (b,c) groups for clarity. For example, 0<=(x,y)<=1 simply means 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1, and no known relationship between x and y. This has drifted far from an English question, and is strictly mathematical notation. I wouldn't trust answers that you're getting here to work in a math paper.

Comment: @Jim well often 0 =< x,y,z =<1  means  x,y,z are between 0 and 1 so it's at least tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to clearly convey your message.

> We know (a > b), (c > d), (e > f), and (f > g).
>
> We know (a > b, c > d, e > f), and (f > g).

Both of those are valid interpretations with different meanings, but you can clarify which is meant through parentheses.

Comment: Even with the parens, I would interpret your second the same as your first.

Comment: @Jim That would be incorrect and it is not how math works.  The first states four unrelated inequalities.  (a) would have no relationship to (c, d, e, f, or g) because it is not being compared to any of those.  The second states 2 inequalities, one of which is compound.  (a) is less than (b and c), which in turn is less than (d and e), meaning we can infer (a) is still less than (d and e).  No such relationship exists in the first line.

Comment: Correct or not, I’m telling you that it would never even occur to me to interpret that in the way that you suggest.  And while I don’t claim to be a mathematician in any way, my engineering degree probably means I’ve taken more math classes than the average world citizen.

Comment: @JRodge01 Don't you mean that **a** is _greater_ than  **b** and **c** which are, in turn, greater than **d** and **e** which are greater than **f**?

Comment: Hah, good catch.